# how to search a specific word in java as well as static files in the existing applications

Tags: search

I have a requirement to search a specific word in static files and as well in java files.

Requirement is not only for the static word search and for dynamic word which are coming from Content Mgmt system.

Goal is to identifying the java and static components which are involved to display the word on the screen.

Example: I would like to replace a "abc" word which is displaying on the UI with some "xyz".

Here abc word is coming static in some files like in HTML and dynamic like coming from Database so here i need to find which java files are involved in this.

Hope the problem description is clear!!

If not, please post with your questions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not entirely clear yet. Here's a question: Does the application use ResourceBundles? Is that how it replaces placeholders with content at runtime?